# Converting text file to list and getting at it using indexes:

Tags: python, list, file, text

Can anyone tell me why this doesn't work (Python 3) and what I need to do to fix it. Code and error message below:

```
def verifylogin():

fin=open("moosebook.txt","r")
data=fin.readlines()
line=data

allData = []
for ln in line.split(')('):
    allData.append( ln.lstrip('(').rstrip(')').replace("'", '').replace(' ', '').split(',') )

for data in allData:
    print (data[0]) # print user
print (data[5]) # print profession
```

output error message:

```
line 30, in verifylogin
for ln in line.split(')('):
```

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'

The data in the text file is:

```
('CoderBlogJ', 'ggs123', 'J', 'Bloggs', 'Male', 'Coder')('DoctorSmitD', 'ith123', 'D', 'Smith', 'Male', 'Doctor')('teacherminaR', 'neb123', 'R', 'minajneb', 'female', 'teacher')('WriterGardK', 'ens123', 'K', 'Gardens', 'Male', 'Writer')('', '123', '', '', '', '')('', '123', '', '', '', '')('', '123', '', '', '', '')
```

I want data[0] and data[5] etc to print out the relevant field in the list.

Thank you very much for the answer: My final quest however, is to get the username and password to work and because I can't translate it, I can't quite get it to work ....

```
def verifylogin():
    with open("moosebook.txt") as f:
        data = literal_eval(f.read().replace(")", "),"))
    for user, pw,_,sur,_, job in data: 
        if user:
               print("{}  is a {}".format(user, pw))

     flag=0
for counter in range(0,len(data)):
    if textlogin.get()==data[counter] and textpassword.get()==data[counter+1]:
        flag=flag+1

if flag>0:
            welcome=Label(myGui,text="Access Granted. Loading Profile ....")
            welcome.pack()
else:
                denied=Label(myGui,text="Access Denied")
                denied.pack()
```

Comment: line is  a `list`, you are also just creating a reference to data with `line = data` so it seems redundant

Comment: also  [follow this link](https://gist.github.com/Pruthvi-Raj/72a127b61f580dd15888) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error as stated already is because line is a reference to data which is a list, if each tuple is on a separate line in your file you can use ast.literal_eval to parse the data and just index the tuples to get the dat you want:

```
from ast import literal_eval
def verifylogin():

    with open("test.csv") as f:
        for line in f:
            print(literal_eval(line))
verifylogin()
```

Output:

```
('CoderBlogJ', 'ggs123', 'J', 'Bloggs', 'Male', 'Coder')
('DoctorSmitD', 'ith123', 'D', 'Smith', 'Male', 'Doctor')
('teacherminaR', 'neb123', 'R', 'minajneb', 'female', 'teacher')
('WriterGardK', 'ens123', 'K', 'Gardens', 'Male', 'Writer')
('', '123', '', '', '', '')
('', '123', '', '', '', '')
('', '123', '', '', '', '')
```

If you have it all in a single line you can `str.replace` putting a trailing comma after each `)`, that will wrap all the tuples in a tuple so ast can parse the file content correctly:

```
def verifylogin():
    with open("test.csv") as f:
        data = literal_eval(f.read().replace(")", "),"))
        for t in data:
            print(t)


verifylogin()
```

Output will be the same as previously.

If you are using python3 we can use [extended iterable unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/) to get the data we want, ignoring the data with no user with an if check:

```
from ast import literal_eval

def verifylogin():
    with open("test.csv") as f:
        data = literal_eval(f.read().replace(")", "),"))
        for user, *rest, job in data: # python2 ->  for user, _,_,_,_, job in data:
            if user:
                   print("{}  is a {}".format(user, job))
```

Output:

```
CoderBlogJ  is a Coder
DoctorSmitD  is a Doctor
teacherminaR  is a teacher
WriterGardK  is a Writer
```

You can get whatever info you want, all the data is unpacked in the loop:

```
def verifylogin():
    with open("test.csv") as f:
        data = literal_eval(f.read().replace(")", "),"))
        for user, pw, _, _ , _, job in data:
            if user:
                print("Details for user: {}\nPassword: {}\nJob: {}\n".format(user, pw, job))
```

Output:

```
Details for user: DoctorSmitD
Password: ith123
Job: Doctor

Details for user: teacherminaR
Password: neb123
Job: teacher

Details for user: WriterGardK
Password: ens123
Job: Writer
```

Comment: plus 1, beat me to it :)

Comment: Padraic - I'm not sure how you did that so fast!!! Thank you. However, I really don't understand what the code means so can't edit it. For instance, what I really want is to Print: Username is: CoderBlogJ and password is: ggs123 (or somehow get the values of CoderBlogJ into data[0] and ggs123 the next stored value which is the password into data[2] so that I can use a loop to search for a match. Using the above code, how would i print Username: CoderBlogJ and password: ggs123 and so on for each field in the list? - that's what I'm trying to get at...

Comment: @Compoot,  I added another example, all the data is stored in each tuple, we just unpack and use whichever you want, if we wanted all six values we would simply `for user, pw, ini, sur, sx, job in data:`, you might find using a dict easier and dumping the dict to file, either with json or pickle

Comment: Thank you - what I'm ultimately trying to do is read to check for a username and password check. That's what I can't translate it into....sigh! (have redited original code)

Comment: user is the user pw is the password so `if user == your_user and pw == your_password`

Answer (score 1):

`file.readlines()` returns a list of lines in.

you did:-

`data = fin.readlines()`

then `data` is a `list` not `string`

```
line = data
```

`line` is a `list` too, and `list` don't have `split` method.

Try `type()` function.

```
 type(data.readlines())
 list
```

Comment: `for ln in line.split(')('):` what you wanna do at this line?

Answer (score 0):

With the format of the data you give (one line with multiple tuples), and keeping your code, try the following.

```
def verifylogin():
    fin = open("moosebook.txt", "r")
    data = fin.readlines()

    allData = []
    for line in data:
            for ln in line.split(')('):
                allData.append(ln.lstrip('(').rstrip(')').replace("'", '').replace(' ', '').split(','))

    for data in allData:
        print(data[0])  # print user
        print(data[5])  # print profession

verifylogin()
```